# Socket.io disconnects sockets after 5min, even if the page is still active

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am building a website that relies on an express.js server with socket.io (v4.6.1) setup to exchange data with the client. I can open socket connections and exchange messages just fine, but for some reason the sockets always disconnect exactly 5min after their creation, even if the page is still active and information was transmitted through the socket seconds earlier.

Here is the server side code:

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use(express.static('src'));
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

http.listen(port , () => {
    console.log("HTTP listening on port " + port + ".");
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    //do stuff
});
```

And here is the client side code, which is run after the socket.io script:

```
const socket = io();
socket.on('message', () => {
    //do stuff
});
```

How can I configure socket.io to avoid any unwanted disconnection, which I assume is related to a timeout of some sort?

Comment: This sounds like it's likely something in your hosting infrastructure (most often a proxy) that is trying to limit how long a socket can stay open.  A socket.io connection will usually automatically reconnect.  If the auto-reconnect is not a sufficient solution, then you would have to look into the hosting infrastructure and see if it is configurable.

Comment: FYI, socket.io has no built-in limits on the duration of a connection.

Comment: Alright thank you for your answers. I'll have to look at what I can do on the host side, and even if it's suboptimal I might have to tinker with reconnections.